# What is iframe used for?

Tags: html, iframe

What is the purpose of the iframe tag in HTML? What is it used for?

Answer (score 15):

An <iframe> is used for containing (X)HTML documents in other (X)HTML documents. This enables updates of parts of a website while the user browses, without making them reload the whole thing. (This is now largely replaced by [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29)).

Also, see:

http://w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_iframe.asp

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML_element#Frames

Comment: So what's the point of iframe now?

Answer (score 6):

Be careful. <iframe> tags are becoming less common.

I wouldn't use iframes except in really specific cases, because it is nonstandard.

here is the [link](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-iframe-element)

However, Google images still uses <iframe> tags.