# How do I make a frame compatible with anchor

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I have tried to test other questions using StackOverflow, but I couldn't get it to work.

The frame will not scroll to the anchor.

```html
<iframe src="http://coder0.weebly.com/browsers-images.html#B0" width="95%" height="50"  target="_parant" id="comfra" frameborder="0" scrolling="no">
<p><a href="browser-not-supported">Please click here</a></p>
</iframe>
```

The id is B0.

Comment: You can't put contents inside an `<iframe>`, it gets all its contents from the URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The iframe can't be used like that. Please check: [What is iframe used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4232067/what-is-iframe-used-for)

You can't add content to an iframe tag like that.

You can check this javascript solution:
[Insert content into iFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795761/insert-content-into-iframe)